# OCamlbuild recursively build dependecies

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

I’m building a project that uses [OCamlbuild](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild) as its build system. This project also requires a library, which also uses OCamlbuild. This library comes with `.mlpack`, `_tags`, and `myocamlbuild.ml` files. I have included the library into my project as a git submodule in the path `lib/mylib` starting from the project’s root.

I’d like to tell OCamlbuild to recursively compile the library, as I would to with a `make -C lib/mylib` in a `Makefile`.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a comment: Dune has first-class support for this kind of workflows ("composable build system"), so you might find it more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer is described in [Working on dependent projects with OCamlbuild](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/ocamlbuild/Working_on_dependent_projects_with_ocamlbuild.html).
Basically, add `<lib/mylib>: include` to `_tags` and import the library `myocamlbuild.ml`. It does seem a bit wobbly.

Or use [Dune](https://dune.build/).